# unconfirmed transaction more than 1 month 17 days?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

someone please help, unconfirmed transaction for more than 1 month 17 days - https://blockchain.info/tx/3d314e7ffc03fdefba99ce02a33552e0479e1af7cc32cdf70483f4b0405f9f94

Comment: Accelerated using confirmtx.com

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction does not contain commission.

The value of inputs equal to the output values.

May be that's why nobody confirm your TX for a long time.